# Scala generics for generic type

Tags: scala, generics

Suppose I have this code. It does not compile. Compiler seems to think that e in foreach() is not a subclass of MyTrait.

```
class MyCollection[T[A] <: MyTrait[A]](val iterable: Iterable[T]) extends Iterable[T]{
    override def iterator: Iterator[T] = ???
    def doStuffWithAll = iterable.foreach(e => e.doStuff)
}

trait MyTrait[T]{
    def doStuff = println("doing stuff")
}
```

This collection is a wrapper around a collection of implementations of MyTrait and it will have some convenience methods. I want MyTrait to also be generic, and ensure that MyCollection only contains implementations of MyTrait with the type parameter. is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want `T: MyTrait` instead of `T[A] <: MyTrait[A]`? Your kinds don't match up at all....

Comment: If you did intend `T[A]` you need to parameterize `T`: `class MyCollection[T[A] <: MyTrait[A], A](val iterable: Iterable[T[A]]) extends Iterable[T[A]]`

Comment: `T` is type constructor here. I don't think `Iterable[T]` makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Alec exactly what do you mean do you mean kinds dont match at all? And, yes, I also want to parameterize MyTrait. I think the solution I wanted is class MyCollection[T <: MyTrait[A], A]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MyTrait[A]` as the type to give your `Iterator`

```
class MyCollection[A](iterable: Iterable[MyTrait[A]]) extends Iterable[MyTrait[A]] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[MyTrait[A]] = ???
  def doStuffWithAll = iterable.foreach(_.doStuff)
}
```

If you want to do it the way you are attempting, you forget to pass `A` as a type parameter.

```
class MyCollection[A, T[A] <: MyTrait[A]](iterable: Iterable[T[A]]) extends Iterable[T[A]] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[T[A]] = ???
  def doStuffWithAll = iterable.foreach(_.doStuff)
}
```